# "Elemental Burst's" action type?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monk, unchained

Okay, here's the entry for the Unchained Monk's level 18 Ki power:

> 18th level required: Elemental Burst (Su): A monk with this ability
> can spend 4 ki points to unleash a gout of energy in a 30-foot cone.
> Creatures within the cone take 20d6 points of damage of the same type
> as the monk’s elemental fury ki power. A Reflex save (DC = 10 + 1/2
> the monk’s level + his Wisdom modifier) halves the damage. A monk must
> be at least 18th level and must possess the elemental fury ki power
> before selecting this ki power.

Unfortunately, this description entry doesn't specify what this ability's action type is. It is a standard, swift or full action? I've been looking around online and haven't found anything on it. Anyone here have any idea what, if any, official ruling there is on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Standard Action

Unless otherwise noted, a supernatural ability requires a standard action to activate:

> [Use Special Ability](https://www.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Use%20Special%20Ability&Category=Standard%20Actions)
>
> **Supernatural Abilities (Su):** Using a supernatural ability is usually a
> standard action (unless defined otherwise by the ability’s
> description). Its use cannot be disrupted, does not require
> concentration, and does not provoke attacks of opportunity.